# run tasks on google app engine that runs my app server

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron, google-appengine-node

I am using nodejs on google app engine with an end point for a cron job. When the rest end point is called I want to proceed with my cron job after returning the response back to the caller.The cron task will continue for about an hour. Will GAE terminate the task if it runs for an hour or more ? I suppose GAE should not kill my nodejs server process because that way my application will stop. I want to know if there is any possibility for the task to end prematurely due to some restrictions on GAE.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which type of scaling you have selected: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine

Requests on Basic & Manual Scaling can run indefinitely, Automatic scaling has a 60 second deadline for http requests & 10 minutes for task queue requests. If you're not sure which type of scaling you have you probably have Automatic.

You could setup a micro-service with Basic scaling specifically for tasks like this; so that your primary service can stay on Automatic scaling.

You could also split up your cron task into several tasks, and then daisy-chain them using push queues (i.e. you cron task launches, does some work, and then launches task2 and dies. task2 launches, does some work, launches task3 and dies. etc)